# Pass offset to memory region in a linker file

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I build different firmwares that are loaded at custom addresses (a bootloader and a loadable firmware).

The bootloader starts at 0x0 and the loadable firmware starts at 0x3000.

So I have two linker files, for the bootloader:

```
/* ... */
MEMORY
{
  interrupts    (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0xC0
  cfmprotrom    (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000400, LENGTH = 0x10
  text      (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000800, LENGTH = 128K - 0x800
  data     (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x1FFFF000, LENGTH = 16K        /* SRAM */
}

SECTIONS
{
/* ... */
}
```

The other one is exactly the same except for some of the memory areas that have an offset (0x3000).

Since both linker files are almost the same, I'd like to use only one, specifying an offset address from command line.

I am aware of the linker `INCLUDE` command that would be useful here but it's not dynamic.

I don't know if this is the common way but is it possible to specify an offset address for some of these areas from command line or using `INCLUDE` is the right way to go ?